# How does the DAI Masterwork RNG works?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Does anybody knows how the Masterwork RNG in DAI works?

Out of 10 tries with reloading, still no luck and the chance is 30%.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy

Comment: Some games (I don't know if Dragon Age is one) reload the random seed if you reload. This means if you reload and perform the same action, you get the same results.

Comment: However, because of your outrageously tiny sample size (I sincerely hope you don't consider 10 an appropriate sample for testing an RNG), it's possible this is just bad luck. The chance of this happening is actually about 1/40.

Comment: this is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 3):

DA:I stores the random seed it uses for determining if an item is a masterwork, so saving and reloading will not work.

However, a side effect of this storing is that it makes the occurrence of successes deterministic. So if, for example, if you have 5 great bear claws and you use them in crafting and you see that there is a critical success on the third and fifth bear claw, this will still be true if you load a save file you made before the crafting. This indformation can be used to your advantage:

- Save
- As an experiment use up your crafting material by crafting random items. Note which attempts were successful
- Load
- Craft a junk item when your experiment showed a failure and an item that you want to use when your experiment showed a success.

This way you don't waste your other good crafting materials on a masterwork failure.

Also note that each critical crafting material type has its own random seed. You have to experiment with them independently.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2018 and i only got to play DAI recently, so yeah it's old. But i did find clues that might answer this RNG stuff. Not that i need it, done with the game.

Apparently the save and reload method basically still works to affect % success in save scumming (and likely crafting too). Looks like the game code can't deviate from this. But apparently game devs anticipated these and came up with some defensive variables. I found these when i was save-scumming for schematics

The first i found is the type of save file. The quick save and quick reload is specifically guarded, so don't rely on them. Use manual save and reload.

Second, strangely, is distance. saving the game when your character is directly in front of an interactable object (chests, weapon/armor maker etc) will negate the save file's randomizing effect. so if you want different result, don't save too close. in the case of scumming chests it was around 6-7 meters away.

that's what i found. any interested inquisitors might want to investigate whi